# How do I stop Python from splitting a double digit integer into two single integers in my code

Tags: python, loops

This is the task

Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True: 
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        intnum = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid')
        continue
    for size in (num):
        if largest is None: 
            largest = size
        if smallest is None: 
            smallest = size
        if largest < size:
            largest = size
        if smallest > size:
            smallest = (size)
   

print("Maximum is", largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)type here
```

The code works when I use one digit numbers but if i use a double digit number like 10 then then it prints 0 as the smallest number

for example if I entered

```
1,3,10,2,6, done
```

even though the smallest number is 1 it would print:

```
maximum is 6
minimum is 0
```

I'm struggling to figure it out so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you don't need that loop. take it out and try it

Comment: Use `intnum`. `num` is a string and the loop iterates over the individual characters of the string. You don’t need the loop

Comment: this looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.

Comment: Once you have `intnum`, you don't need `num` anymore. You certainly don't want to iterate over the *digits* in `num`.

Comment: Its not homework I am self studying and its one of the exercises in the python for everyone book.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right, you can remove the for loop and just compare the maximum and minimum values with the `intnum` variable. The code would look like this.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        intnum = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid')
        continue
    if largest is None:
        largest = intnum
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = intnum
    if largest < intnum:
        largest = intnum
    if smallest > intnum:
        smallest = (intnum)

print("Maximum is", largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

This works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce if statement by apply reverse cycology.

**From starting initializing largest with the smallest value i.e`(float('-inf'))` and smallest with the largest value i.e.`(float('inf'))`**

and checking the user input if the `number>largest` modify `largest`. `number<smallest` modify `smallest`

**One edgecase** let's say user not input any number directly rights done than it will print `inf` `-inf` which is not correct. so just converted them into `no minimum` `no maximum`

**Code:**

```
largest = float('-inf')
smallest = float('inf')

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num.lower() == "done":  #Works for Done also..
        break
    try:
        intnum = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid')
        continue
    if intnum>largest:
        largest=intnum
    if intnum<smallest:
        smallest = intnum

print("Maximum is", largest if largest!=float('-inf') else 'No maximum')
print('Minimum is', smallest if smallest!=float('inf') else 'No minimum')
```

Also you can take both `if` inside the try statement also..!

**Output:**

**When user not input any number**

```
Enter a number: done
Maximum is No maximum
Minimum is No minimum
```

**When user input only one number**

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: done
Maximum is 4
Minimum is 4
```

**Normal case when user input more than 1 number**

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 9
Enter a number: done
Maximum is 9
Minimum is 1
```